# How are the row heights in an SSRS tablix calculated?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I am wondering how the row heights in an SSRS tablix are calculated.

For instance, I have data for which the displayed and grouped by columns are close enough to be identical. However, some rows will for some unknown reason have a massive height with a lot of blank space. If you inspect the HTML output you can see that these rows have a `rowspan` and `height` applied to them.

This is not a wrapping issue as I can do an `IIf` on that row's item id and simply display `"a"` instead of the actual values and *still* get abnormal height.  I have also disabled `CanGrow` on all textboxes/rows etc. and have set manual heights yet the issue persists.

What causes this behaviour and how are the row heights usually calculated?

Comment: What is the exact version of SQL Server that you are running?

Comment: Just curious... How does it display in the WindowsForms report viewer? Or how does it display when exported as PDF?

Also check you haven't put some bindings to any properties other than the ones you meant to (look at the RDL) reports allow binding of many aspects of the report not just the values you see...

Comment: Late answers sorry guys - @alison - 2008, @MikeG - identical problem, couldn't see any other bindings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of possibilities as to what is going on:

1. SQL Server 2008 (fully patched) has a bug in that padding can sometimes be added for certain datatypes.  Take a look at [this page](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/484263/pdf-rendering-issue-with-report-builder-report) for more details.  The link isn't covering exactly your issue but a support person from Microsoft does claim it to be a bug and very likely extends to your issue, as well.  Supposedly, upgrading to SQL Server 2008 R2 resolves the issue.
2. Assuming that you aren't going to upgrade SQL Server, there are a couple of things for you to check:

   - Make sure that the row height is not set to a height smaller than the default.  keep the height at least as large as the default.
   - Adjusting the padding settings so that the top and bottom padding is set to zero (as others have mentioned) to Padding: 2,2, 0, 0
   - Take a look at [this page for a more in-depth description](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2007/10/26/ssrs-invalid-row-heights-bug.aspx). The article is a few years old but the information likely still applies.

Comment: Yes. I've seen the same bug which is what I based my earlier answer on.

Comment: This is the most comprehensive answer here. It should hopefully help others. I have found that after recreating a lot of the tablix and changing the grouping nature it *appears* to be gone (though the data may be different). However, I'm still not sure why and the rdl doesn't seem to reveal anything key. The proposed solutions were all appreciated though.

Comment: +1 for removing the padding. I thought I'd tried everything... and now that seems very obvious in retrospect. :P

Answer (score 4):

Try setting the following properties for your rows and see if it helps.

- Padding: 2pt, 2pt, 0pt, 0pt
- VerticalAlign: Middle
- CanGrow: False
- CanShrink: False

Comment: Thanks I tried those (it appears to be a common answer) but no luck. Still appreciated nonetheless.

Comment: For me the culprit property was CanGrow being set to true. Thanks for your answer! This was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

One thing to check is the datatype.  Older datatypes have padding added to them.  Newer (varchar, nvarchar, etc.) would be better, if that's what's happening.

Comment: They're all varchars but only one of the varchars columns causes padding. Still appreciate your help though so thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  All the responses thus far are correct, but they don't mention the one thing that can lead a developer to assume the row height cannot be adjusted.
To recap...

- Highlight the Tablix Row you want to change the height on.
- Change the row properties CanGrow=False, CanShrink=True
- Changes to Padding refers to the space above (Top) and below (Bottom) your cell values within the cell.
- Here's the new thing:  If your tablix is adjacent to another control it will lock onto that controls height and not let you shrink the row with row header up/down arrow.  So you need to drag the whole tablix to some open white space with no other controls adjacent to it.  Then the row height will not lock and you can place it exactly where you need it and it will stay put.  Then you carefully move the Tablix back to it's permanent location.

It's this locking to adjacent controls that leads developers to conclude that height can't be adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

GOT HUGE problems with show/hide rows and CanShrink/CanGrow din't work, so I found out that there was a "Row visibillity" expression, that show/hides the whole row depend of a Textbox value.

(Right click the tablixrow and choose "Row visibility")
[image: Show/Hide row visibility]

Cheers

Comment: Have been looking for this everywhere! Solved my problem. One thing that would be helpful is to add to the content how to open this window. Something like: Right Click on row selector icon and then select "Row Visibility..."

Answer (score 0):

I've found one other thing to consider. When you select a lengthy field that you want to group by and then shrink the horizontal size, the field will display vertically. If a field length goes beyond the size you set for the total vertical length of the group, then the last row will increase to compensate. The left side of the image shows the additional space to the last row. Once I adjusted the field length to less that the total height of the group, then the last row appears as normal. [lengths of rows image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zEyE.png)